# Delete '\n' from values of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary, newline

How can I delete the '\n' from the values in dictionary ?

```
files_dict = {}
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/kk/Desktop/e"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        key = file.split(".")[0]
        
        full_filename = os.path.join("C:/Users/kk/Desktop/e", file)
        with open(full_filename, "r") as f:
            files_dict[key] = f.readlines()

pprint.pprint(files_dict)

value_list1 = files_dict['f1']
print('Values of f1 are:')
print(value_list1)
```

the output

```
Values of f1 are:
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n']
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output you're currently getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `.readlines()` returns a list of each line, including the terminating newline. `.read().split('\n')` will read all data, and split it into a list on the newlines.

```py
files_dict = {}
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/kk/Desktop/e"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        key = file.split(".")[0]
        
        full_filename = os.path.join("C:/Users/kk/Desktop/e", file)
        with open(full_filename, "r") as f:
            files_dict[key] = f.read().split('\n')
## Heading ##
pprint.pprint(files_dict)

value_list1 = files_dict['f1']
print('Values of f1 are:')
print(value_list1)
```

Comment: Python converts all newline types to `\n` by default.

Comment: @chepner Interesting! Edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please use default file.read().splitlines() no need to reivent the wheel.